# Angular bootstrap calendar month view open popup issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am following an example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/qydhJB1X6Edd4TDigk9g?p=options).

I want to achieve same functionality, like in month view when I click on event it is opening a popup with details.But somehow I am not able to achieve it. Following is the code I am experimenting with,

```
     app.module('mwl.calendar.docs')
        .controller('AppointmentsController',
                function ($rootScope, $scope, CalenderService, $location, ProjREST_URL, $state,
                        moment,alert, calendarConfig, $timeout, propSettingService, DetailService) {

    -----------------
    -----------------
 });
    angular
      .module('mwl.calendar.docs')
      .factory('alert', function($uibModal) {

        function show(action, event) {
          return $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl: 'modalContent.html',
            controller: function() {
              var vm = this;
              vm.action = action;
              vm.event = event;
            },
            controllerAs: 'vm'
          });
        }

        return {
          show: show
        };

      });
```

Both controller and factory is in same js
But i am getting an error,

```
Uncaught TypeError: app.module is not a function
```

I am new to angular, so what i am doing something silly here :)
Any help is really appreciated. Thanks

---

Updated code looks like, still the error remains same

```
angular.module('mwl.calendar.docs', ['mwl.calendar', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap', 'colorpicker.module']);

app
.module('mwl.calendar.docs')
.controller('AppointmentsController',
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare your module before registering a controller:

```
angular.module('mwl.calendar.docs', ['mwl.calendar', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap', 'colorpicker.module']);
```

Comment: Ok this solves the issue
angular.module('app').controller('AppointmentsController',
['$rootScope', '$scope', 'CalenderService', '$location', 'REST_URL', '$state',
                'moment', 'calendarConfig', '$timeout', 'AgeSettingService', 'MasterService', '$uibModal',
        function ($rootScope, $scope, CalanderService, $location, REST_URL, $state,
                moment, calendarConfig, $timeout, AgeSettingService, MasterService, $modal) {